# In Haskell how do you remove a duplicate list with different order than the original?

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to find all ways to combine number in a certain group size without any repeats using Haskell. I currently have a list like this:

```
[[1,1,1],[1,1,2],[1,2,1],[1,2,2],[2,1,1],[2,1,2],[2,2,1],[2,2,2]]
```

[1,1,2] [1,2,1] [2,1,1] are all duplicates of each other even though the order differs. How could I remove the duplicates from the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In many cases, a better solution is to avoid generating the duplicates in the first place. For example, here's a naive way of generating the list you have:

```
listsOfSize 0 xs = [[]]
listsOfSize n xs = do
    first <- xs
    rest  <- listsOfSize (n-1) xs
    return (first:rest)
```

I would bet you have this or something very like it in your code base generating the list you suggested you "have". It is not too hard to change the way this generates lists to never generate duplicates (provided the input list has no duplicates). The idea is to generate lists that are in "sorted" order: once we have chosen an element of the input list, we will refuse to later choose an earlier element of that list. That looks like this:

```
import Data.List

risingListsOfSize 0 xs = [[]]
risingListsOfSize n xs = do
    choicesForRest@(first:_) <- tails xs
    rest <- risingListsOfSize (n-1) choicesForRest
    return (first:rest)
```

Then we simply do not generate the duplicates:

```
*Main> risingListsOfSize 3 [1,2]
[[1,1,1],[1,1,2],[1,2,2],[2,2,2]]
```

Answer (score 1):

To obtain only unique elements, first you need to `sort` each list of your list and then use remove duplicate elements :

```
import Data.List
lst = [[1,1,1],[1,1,2],[1,2,1],[1,2,2],[2,1,1],[2,1,2],[2,2,1],[2,2,2]]

getUniqueLists :: (Ord a) => [[a]] -> [[a]]
getUniqueList xs = nub ( map sort xs)
```

where `map sort xs` will sort your inner lists

```
[[1,1,1],[1,1,2],[1,1,2],[1,2,2],[1,1,2],[1,2,2],[1,2,2],[2,2,2]]
```

and `nub` will remove the duplicate elements:

```
[[1,1,1],[1,1,2],[1,2,2],[2,2,2]]
```

You can also write this in point free style :

```
getUniqueList = nub . map sort
```